# SQLite как использовать Join в Update

Tags: sql, sqlite

Есть две таблицы

**tab_1**

```
| id | name | desc |
```

**tab_2**

```
| id | tab_id | desc |
```

Как из tab_2 забрать данные из столбца desc и вставить в tab_1 столбец desc?

Я пробовал разные запросы, но выходят ошибки, гуглил, не помогло :):

```
UPDATE tab_1, tab_2
SET tab_1.desc = tab_2.desc
WHERE tab_1.id = tab_2.tab_id
```

.

```
UPDATE tab_1
SET tab_1.desc = tab_2.desc
JOIN tab_2 ON tab_1.id = tab_2.tab_id
```

.

```
UPDATE tab_1
SET tab_1.desc = (SELECT desc
FROM tab_2)
WHERE tab_1.id = tab_2.tab_id
```

Подскажите, использую sqlite3 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite не поддерживает оператор `Join` в `Update` - [документация](https://sqlite.org/lang_update.html)

Можно воспользоваться коррелированным подзапросом для обновления данных.
Запрос для обновления будет выглядеть так:

```
UPDATE 
      tab_1
SET desc = (SELECT desc
                  FROM tab_2
                  WHERE id = tab_1.id) 
where EXISTS (SELECT desc
                  FROM tab_2
                  WHERE id = tab_1.id)
```

Обязаталельно необходимо проверять с помощью `EXISTS` существует ли обновляемая запись во второй таблице, иначе вы получите `Null` значения для отсутствующих записей.

Пример работы, а так же, к чему приведет отсутствие `EXISTS`, можно увидеть тут [фиддл](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=27ad472fc806492c33b84b63450f12d3)

Для ответа была использована информация из [вопроса на SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19270259/update-with-join-in-sqlite)